# Superfish Menu - Submenus (Child Menus) first link is always ParentMenu link. How to remove this?

Tags: navigation

In my superfish menus, sub-menus (child-menus) show parent menu link as 1st option. Always. How do I remove this? See the photo for example: [image]

Comment: see if it help https://www.drupal.org/node/2032759

Comment: Have u changed the plugin version? , if so please post it as answer